# Issue with Summarizing value in DAX

Tags: powerbi, report, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset with consumption data of multiple Machines for each day. The table also contains Parts information to identify how many parts needs to be exchanged or checked on a particular day.

The dashboard has to display consumption data in the form of a line and parts checked or exchanged in column chart.

**Sample Data table:**

[image]

**I want to summarize consumption based on Months in a Line and Column chart.** I have created the below **Measure in DAX** called **Consumptionactual**

```
consumptionactual = SUMX(DISTINCT(ReportMaintenance[Consumption]),FIRSTNONBLANK(ReportMaintenance[Consumption], 0))
```

[image]

**Instead I should be getting,  Eg. Consumption = 3300 for the whole month if everyday Consumption is 110.**

**If I remove the Distinct clause, I am getting sum of consumption based on every part listed for that particular day, which is also incorrect.** See below,

[image]

I am using the following 2 measures to calculate the number of parts to be checked or changed for a particular day. There will be multiple parts to be checked or changed on a particular day.

```
changeop = CALCULATE(COUNT(ReportMaintenance[MachineId]),FILTER(ReportMaintenance,ReportMaintenance[Operation]="Change"))

checkop = CALCULATE(COUNT(ReportMaintenance[MachineId]),FILTER(ReportMaintenance,ReportMaintenance[Operation]="Check"))
```

Can anyone help in calculating the correct consumption?

Comment: What's the purpose of FIRSTNONBLANK? Why are you using this function in particular (or to what end)? Is SUM(ReportMaintenance[Consumption]) giving you wrong results?